# Open and Close Classes with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a fairly simple `.addClass(open)` function in jQuery, but am having trouble passing the right variables.

I have these two buttons in a sidebar:

```
<ul>
  <li class="dashButton active" id="#1"><?php the_field('sidebar_text_0'); ?></li>
  <li class="dashButton" id="#2"><?php the_field('sidebar_text_1'); ?></li>
</ul>
```

And then two divs that should open in eachother's place when it's button is clicked.  `mainDashWrap` relates to `id=#1` and `editProfile` relates to `id=#2`.

```
<div class="mainDashWrap dashView open">
   ...... content .....
</div>
<div class="editProfile dashView">
   ...... content .....
</div>
```

And my jQuery adds and removes the `open` class, which has `display:none` if there is no `open` class and `display:block` if it does have the open class.

My problem is with the `//Get the attr2` part below.  I don't think it's properly setting the class so that it's formatted to go into the `$(newSect).slideDown()` function.

```
                $('.dashButton').click(function() {

                    //Switch active Tab Buttons and close the Menu.
                    $('.dashButton.active').removeClass('active');
                        $(this).addClass('active');
                        $('.dashView.open').removeClass('open');

                        //Get the attr2 
                        if ( this.id == '#1') {
                            var attr2 = '.mainDashWrap';
                        }
                        else { var attr2 = '.editProfile' }

                        switchDashViews(attr2);
                });

                function switchDashViews(newSect) {

                    //close active section
                    $('.dashView.open').slideUp('2000', function() {
                        $('.dashView.open').removeClass('open');
                        $(newSect).slideDown('2000', function() { 
                            $(newSect).addClass('open');
                        });
                    });
                };
```

This will add and remove the `open` class and hide the dashview that doesn't have the `open` class, but it will not add the `open` class to `newSect` or slide down `newSect`.  How can I get attr2/newsect to set properly?

Comment: Nice question. Can you demonstrate the problem with a fiddle?

Comment: Just an FYI: `#1` and `#2` are not valid ids. Use more meaningful names such as `dashBtn1` and `dashBtn2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove `#` from your id in your HTML, it is not a allowed character in id, *(Imagine what selector will look like `$(##1)`, pretty bad, huh?).*
2. Add a `data-attribute` so that you can get rid of `if() .. else() ...`

#### HTML

```
<ul>
  <li class="dashButton active" data-class=".mainDashWrap" id="1"><?php the_field('sidebar_text_0'); ?></li>
  <li class="dashButton" data-class=".editProfile" id="2"><?php the_field('sidebar_text_1'); ?></li>
</ul>
```

### jQuery

```
$('.dashButton').click(function() {

                    //Switch active Tab Buttons and close the Menu.
                    $('.dashButton.active').removeClass('active');
                        $(this).addClass('active');
                        $('.dashView.open').removeClass('open');

                        // Do this
                        var attr2 = $(this).data("class");

                        /* Or you can do this
                        if ( this.id == '1') {
                           var attr2 = '.mainDashWrap';
                        }
                        else { var attr2 = '.editProfile' }
                        */

                        switchDashViews(attr2);
                });

                function switchDashViews(newSect) {

                    //close active section
                    $('.dashView.open').slideUp('2000', function() {
                        $('.dashView.open').removeClass('open');
                        $(newSect).slideDown('2000', function() { 
                            $(newSect).addClass('open');
                        });
                    });
                };
```

Make sense?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you first removed all `.open` in click event

```
$('.dashView.open').removeClass('open');
```

and only after that trying to slide up this elements in `switchDashViews` function

```
$('.dashView.open').slideUp('2000'...
```

But `.open` are already deleted

**Upd**. try not to use `var` keywords in this block

```
if ( this.id == '#1') {
    var attr2 = '.mainDashWrap';
}
else { var attr2 = '.editProfile' }
```

because `attr2` can be out of scope. Just

```
if ( this.id == '#1') {
    attr2 = '.mainDashWrap';
}
else { attr2 = '.editProfile' }
```

Comment: realized that this is not all the wauestion, made an update

Answer (score 0):

Don't include `#` in the ID. While it's legal in modern browsers, it's confusing and will make it difficult to access the element using jQuery or CSS selectors. Instead use

```
<li class="dashButton active" id="1">
```

Then change the `if` to match this:

```
if (this.id = "1")
```

I also suggest you use more meaningful IDs than just numbers.

Answer (score 0):

**this** can be different depending on the function scope, try to use **event.target** instead so **this.id** would be **event.target.id**.
See your example of your code with changes:

```
            $('.dashButton').click(function(event) {

                //Switch active Tab Buttons and close the Menu.
                $('.dashButton.active').removeClass('active');
                    $(this).addClass('active');
                    $('.dashView.open').removeClass('open');

                    //Get the attr2 
                    if ( event.target.id == '#1') {
                        var attr2 = '.mainDashWrap';
                    }
                    else { var attr2 = '.editProfile' }

                    switchDashViews(attr2);
            });

            function switchDashViews(newSect) {

                //close active section
                $('.dashView.open').slideUp('2000', function() {
                    $('.dashView.open').removeClass('open');
                    $(newSect).slideDown('2000', function() { 
                        $(newSect).addClass('open');
                    });
                });
            };
```

Answer (score -2):

I think `this.id` won't work. ~~You want to convert `this` to a jQuery object via `$(this)` then use the `attr()` method to retrieve the 'id'. So something like...~~

**EDIT**

Turns out `this.id` does work! Didn't notice the `id="#1"` you had in your HTML tags. Yep, as others have pointed out, that'll be the culprit.

Comment: There's no difference between `$(this).attr('id')` and `this.id`, except the latter is faster.

Comment: @Barmar Cool, didn't know that. Thanks!

Comment: How did you think you accessed the ID if you're not using jQuery?

Comment: Guess I'd never needed to. Every time I'd use some vanilla js with `document.getElementById()` or something, I'd always have the ID via some other means. Makes sense there'd be a vanilla way to retrieve that attribute, just haven't used it before. You learn something new every day!